# Sequential coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to understand how sequential coroutines work in Kotlin.

The next sample will run them sequentially:

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    launch {
        delay(1000) // Note the delay
        println("A")
    }.join()

    launch {
        println("B")
    }.join()
}
```

Being the result, "A"-->"B"

But when running next, the result is "B"-->"A", which is what I can't understand:

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {

    val jobA = launch {
        delay(1000)
        println("A")
    }

    val jobB = launch {
        println("B")
    }

    jobA.join()
    jobB.join()
}
```

As I'm calling **jobA.join()** first, I would had thought it would wait until completes before executing jobB, regardless if jobA calls a delay.
What would be the explanation for this? And how can then jobs instances be executed sequentially with delays inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, you launched two coroutines that go on executing concurrently. After that, your top-level coroutine awaits for the first coroutine to complete, and then for the second one. Awaiting on the completion of concurrent coroutines does not interfere with their execution.

Therefore, the coroutines execute as programmed to do, the first one printing after a delay and the second one printing immediately.

Comment: On the second example I can't understand why are launched concurrently as I call jobA.join() which I thought would force to complete the first job before continuing. Is it because the "delay" in jobA is not a blocking call? and then it allows to step to jobB.join() which then executes before the delay in jobA finishes?

Comment: Imagine replacing `launch { }` with `thread { }`. What would you expect to happen then? The correct answer is same as here: you should expect both threads to run on their own, whether you're `join`ing them or not. Coroutines behave like threads, the only difference in behavior occurs when you perform a blocking operation in a coroutine, which is considered an error.

Comment: Right, the `join` call is going wait for the coroutine to finish before moving on but it doesn't mean that the code inside the coroutines _wasn't already running_. As soon as `launch { .. }` is called, that coroutine is running. So they are running concurrently like @MarkoTopolnik says when the `join` calls are moved to the end. The `join` call is just about waiting for it to finish. I'd argue that it is like waiting for a `Future`: it will typically already be running and calling `Future.get()` just waits for it to finish and would be the equivalent of `join` here.